# How do you extude along a specified axis?

Tags: extrude, transform-orientation

How do you extrude along a specific axis?

Answer (score 4):

Specifically when in edit mode and wanting to extrude along a specific axis orientation, you can set *Transform Orientations* to cursor. [image]

Then in the view panel, set the cursor rotation to the orientation you want to extrude along.
[image]

Then simply extrude. Pressing the key <kbd>E</kbd> starts an extrusion, then you press the axis key you want ie <kbd>Z</kbd>, you can use mouse to set visually, or  then just enter the number value.

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>to commit the extrusion.
Alternately you can set *Transform Orientations* to normal, setting *Transform Orientations* to local will refer to the objects transform orientation.